# My attempt at Dijkstra's Algorithm in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, graph

I am practicing my coding at HackerRank. The exact problem statement can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bfsshortreach), but to summarize, it is finding the distances of the shortest path from a starting node to every other node in a non-directional graph where every edge is weighted 6. If a node is unreachable, the distance is -1. The nodes are named 1 to n. If you want an example, please see the provided one in the link.

To solve this, I googled an explanation of Dijkstra's Algorithm and tried my best to implement it (I am new to graph problems). My program passes 6/7 of the test cases, but it times out on the 7th. I improved some small inefficiencies, but it wasn't enough. Please advise me on how I may make the following faster:

```
def shortest (start, nodes, adj):
    unique = [] #this part is pretty standard for this Algorithm I think
    distance = [float('inf')]*nodes
    for i in range(1, nodes+1):
        if (len(adj[i-1])>0):
            unique.append(i)
    distance [start-1] = 0
    while (len(unique)>0):
        minDist = float('inf')
        for i in unique:
            if (distance[i-1] <= minDist):
                minDist = distance[i-1]
                distIndex = i
        current = distIndex #sets the current node as the closest unvisited node
        unique.remove(current)
        for i in adj[current-1]: #updates the distance of each neighbour of the current node
                neigh = i
                temp = 6 + distance[current-1] #edges are 6
                if temp < distance[neigh-1]:
                    distance[neigh-1] = temp
    return distance     


q = int(input()) #each test case contains multiple problems, so just consider one iteration

for i in range(q):
    a = [] #for input purposes
    b = [] #for output purposes
    node = 0
    edge = 0

    #start of input
    node, edge = list(map(int, input().strip().split())) #the input begins with the number of nodes and edges in the graph
    for j in range(edge):
        a.append(list(map(int, input().strip().split()))) #reading the edges, which are all inputted next
    starting = int(input()) #reading the starting node
    #end of input

    adj = [[] for x in range(node)] #the adjacency matrix
    for j in a: #making the adjacency matrix from the inputted edges
        adj[j[0]-1].append(j[1])   
        adj[j[1]-1].append(j[0])
    for j in adj:
        j = list(set(j)) #someone warned that the problematic test case gives the same edge many times, so this is to remove duplicates

    b = shortest(starting, node, adj)

    #formatting the output to what the question required
    b.remove(0)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] == float('inf'):
            b[i] = -1
    print (" ".join(str(e) for e in b))
```

If it helps, I 'purchased' the [test case](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l29a2jw8j54mz3x/testcase.txt?dl=0) which is timing out.

Comment: Make sure you copied the code correctly. I get `NameError: name 'node' is not defined`.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I did it in the provided terminal at HackerRank and it compiled there. It seems that the `node, edge` line is not valid syntax elsewhere. When I change it to read to a list first and then assign node and edge, the next error is for mixing spaces and tabs (it didn't matter in the HackerRank terminal again, sorry). I have to go right now, but I will try to clean it as soon as I get back. 2. The first link to HackerRank has a Sample Input, Sample Output, and Explanation on the page. The second link is just the input of the problematic test case.

Comment: Never mind, I'll just be a little late. I needed to declare `node` and `edge` first (not what I originally thought), and I used a text editor to change the indentation to be consistent with spaces. Please try again.

Comment: Now it breaks because `adj` is length 0 on the first iteration.

Comment: You probably just needed to swap the `adj =` and the `node, edge =` lines.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I put the adj after the node value is read. I was in a rush, sorry, but I tried some inputs this time and it seems fine now.

Comment: Would you mind providing the failing test case here?  Your link doesn't seem to be working: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4eyeC.png

Comment: Copied it to a text file and uploaded it. The link is to a dropbox now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those comments are very difficult to read.

```
j = list(set(j)) #someone warned that the problematic test case gives the same edge many times, so this is to remove duplicates
```

Format this properly:

```
# The problematic test case gives the same edge many times,
# so this is to remove duplicates
j = list(set(j))
```

Then remove fluff:

```
# Remove duplicates. Helps some test cases.
j = list(set(j))
```

In this case just remove the first comment, because `list(set(...))` is already known to mean *deduplicate*. And remove the second since it's implied by the fact you've written the code.

```
j = list(set(j))
```

Another pair is

```
a = [] # for input purposes
b = [] # for output purposes
```

Don't do this. Just call them

```
descriptive_name_1 = []
descriptive_name_2 = []
```

so you don't need the comment in the first place.

Then there's `q = ...`. So I wrack my brain thinking about what word contains `q`. But it turns out you just meant to write `num_test_cases`. What does that have to do with the letter `q`?

Worse than that is when you outright lie. What would you expect the variable `node` to contain? A node, right? Nope - it contains the total number of nodes.

And you write

```
node = 0
```

so we expect the total number of nodes to be `0` at that point, right? Nope, you immediately change your mind and write

```
node, edge = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```

But OK, fine. At least we know what `nodes` contains, then: multiple `node`s, so a list (or other collection) of lengths of nodes.

Nope, it actually means exactly the same thing as `node`.

A similar comment goes for `edge`, which should be `num_edges`.

Then there's `adj`, which you label "adjacency matrix". Why not just call it `adjacency_matrix` then? But it's not even a dense matrix like that would imply, it's actually a list of per-node adjacencies, so call it `adjacencies`.

Then there's `starting` and `start`, which are the same thing named differently. Call them `start_node` or at least be consistent.

Going back to `b`, you have

```
b = []
```

but again this is a lie, because actually

```
b = shortest(start_node, num_nodes, adjacencies)
```

So just write that.

```
distances = shortest(start_node, num_nodes, adjacencies)
```

For `a`, initialize it as close to usage as possible and call it `edges`.

If you write

```
for j in range(num_edges):
```

you're misleading me into thinking you're going to use the index. When you're not going to, write

```
for _ in range(num_edges):
```

And what's up with that, followed by

```
for j in edges:
```

followed by

```
for j in adjacencies:
```

Is `j` just your general "this is a thing" variable? Most people use `x`, `elem` and `item` for that. Instead, write

```
for _ in range(num_edges):
for edge in edges:
for adjacent in adjacencies:
```

The middle can be

```
for start, end in edges:
```

The comment

```
#edges are 6
```

Isn't coherent. Try

```
# Edges are length 6
```

Instead, though, don't put this information in `shortest` - use `1` and multiply out when using the results.

Don't call variables `temp`. It's a poor name.

You've double-indented the part where you update the neighbours.

Note that

```
num_nodes, num_edges = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```

is just

```
num_nodes, num_edges = map(int, input().strip().split())
```

Why do you do this?

```
for i in adjacencies[current-1]:
    neigh = i
```

Just write

```
for neighbour in adjacencies[current-1]:
```

And the content can be

```
for neighbour in adjacencies[current-1]:
    distance[neighbour-1] = min(distance[neighbour-1], distance[current-1] + 1)
```

Do you not think this whole `-1` thing is getting a bit silly? When reading, just decrement the edge values and starting edge correctly:

```
edges = []
for _ in range(num_edges):
    start, end = map(int, input().strip().split())
    edges.append((start - 1, end - 1))

start_node = int(input()) - 1
```

`while` loops and `if` statements don't need their condition parenthesized, and operators should be spaced properly:

```
while (len(unique)>0):   # before
while len(unique) > 0:   # after
```

Then this is better as just `while unique`.

Don't put spaces before the parentheses in function calls or indexing.

`minDist` should be `min_dist`. You can also start with it set to `num_nodes`, and the same for `distance`'s initialization.

`unique` is a horrible name, and has nothing to do with the variable's purpose. Try `unvisited` instead. It can be initialized as

```
unvisited = [i for i, adj in enumerate(adjacencies) if adj]
```

`distance`, unsurprisingly, does not mean `distance` but instead `distances`. Fix that.

This code:

```
min_dist = num_nodes
for i in unvisited:
    if distances[i] <= min_dist:
        min_dist = distances[i]
        distIndex = i
current = distIndex
```

is just

```
min_dist = num_nodes
for i in unvisited:
    if distances[i] <= min_dist:
        min_dist = distances[i]
        current = i
```

and `current` should be called `closest`. It is simplifiable to

```
closest = min(unvisited, key=lambda x: distances[x])
```

This is faster if you write

```
closest = min(unvisited, key=distances.__getitem__)
```

but the difference isn't vital.

One last thing with `shortest` - rename it to `shortest_distances`.

Put the rest of the code in a `main` function.

If you write

```
def read_pair(decrement):
    x, _, y = input().partition(" ")
    return int(x) - decrement, int(y) - decrement
```

then you can initialize `num_nodes`, `num_edges` and `edges` with

```
num_nodes, num_edges = read_pair(0)
edges = [read_pair(1) for i in range(num_edges)]
```

Note my use of `partition` instead of `split` as IMO it's a better description of the operation here.

Then

```
for adjacent in adjacencies:
    adjacent = list(set(adjacent))
```

doesn't actually work! `adjacent =` only affects the local scope! Instead, you want

```
adjacencies = [list(set(adj)) for adj in adjacencies]
```

which is even better as

```
adjacencies = [set() for _ in range(num_nodes)]
for start, end in edges:
    adjacencies[start].add(end)
    adjacencies[end].add(start)
```

as you never have the large intermediates then, and there's no real point converting back from a set.

This stuff:

```
distances.remove(0)
for i in range(len(distances)):
    if distances[i] == num_nodes:
        distances[i] = -1
    else:
        distances[i] *= 6
print(" ".join(str(e) for e in distances))
```

is just

```
print(*(-1 if i == num_nodes else i * 6 for i in distances if i))
```

Nice, that seems to have made it fast enough, but more important the code is more readable.

We can improve speed further by avoiding `input`, using `sys.stdin` directly to get buffering.

```
def main(lines):
    def read_pair(decrement):
        x, _, y = next(lines).partition(" ")
        return int(x) - decrement, int(y) - decrement

    ...

main(sys.stdin)
```

Note that this change is sufficient on its own to beat the time limit: you can apply it to your original code to pass the test. Note also that you shouldn't mix `input` with `next`; at least on Python 2 this throws an error saying

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Though this error is gone in Python 3, that doesn't leave me feeling good about it.

I'd finish off with

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to make it Python 2 compatible.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

def shortest_distances(start_node, num_nodes, adjacencies):
    distances = [num_nodes] * num_nodes
    unvisited = [i for i, adj in enumerate(adjacencies) if adj]

    distances[start_node] = 0
    while unvisited:
        closest = min(unvisited, key=distances.__getitem__)
        unvisited.remove(closest)

        # Update the distances of each neighbour
        for neighbour in adjacencies[closest]:
            distances[neighbour] = min(distances[neighbour], distances[closest] + 1)

    return distances

def main(lines):
    def read_pair(decrement):
        x, _, y = next(lines).partition(" ")
        return int(x) - decrement, int(y) - decrement

    num_test_cases = int(next(lines))
    for i in range(num_test_cases):
        num_nodes, num_edges = read_pair(0)
        edges = [read_pair(1) for i in range(num_edges)]
        start_node = int(next(lines)) - 1

        adjacencies = [set() for _ in range(num_nodes)]
        for start, end in edges:
            adjacencies[start].add(end)
            adjacencies[end].add(start)

        distances = shortest_distances(start_node, num_nodes, adjacencies)

        print(*(-1 if i == num_nodes else i * 6 for i in distances if i))

main(sys.stdin)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This is very thorough and helpful.

Answer (score 6):

[Veedrac's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139016/11728) has a lot of good points about the quality of the code, so in this answer I'm just going to discuss the performance.

Let's figure out where the time goes by profiling the program using [Python's built-in profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html):

```
$ python -m cProfile -s tottime cr138989.py < testcase.txt
...
         1492053 function calls in 3.915 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.767    1.767    3.915    3.915 cr138989.py:1(<module>)
   246223    1.346    0.000    1.348    0.000 {built-in method builtins.input}
        6    0.343    0.057    0.364    0.061 cr138989.py:1(shortest)
   246216    0.221    0.000    0.221    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   741011    0.106    0.000    0.106    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
   246216    0.062    0.000    0.062    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
        6    0.043    0.007    0.043    0.007 {built-in method builtins.print}
     2387    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
     3403    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 cr138989.py:53(<genexpr>)
        6    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 cr138989.py:39(<listcomp>)
      258    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.ascii_decode}
        6    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
     5796    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
      258    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 ascii.py:25(decode)
      258    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:280(getstate)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.915    3.915 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

It takes some practice to interpret the results, but basically this is telling you that the total runtime was 3.9 seconds, of which 1.7 seconds was spent in the code at the top level of the module, 1.3 seconds was spent in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), 0.3 in `shortest`, and a small amount in other functions.

So the obvious performance problem here is `input`. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), you'll see that this function has several features that you don't use (prompting, interactivity, newline stripping, EOF handling), and all this can easily be avoided by replacing `input` with `sys.stdin.readline`:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readline
```

Now the profile results look like this:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.500    1.500    2.387    2.387 cr138989.py:1(<module>)
        6    0.357    0.059    0.378    0.063 cr138989.py:1(shortest)
   246216    0.151    0.000    0.151    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   246223    0.140    0.000    0.142    0.000 {method 'readline' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
   741011    0.103    0.000    0.103    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
   246216    0.058    0.000    0.058    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
        6    0.052    0.009    0.052    0.009 {built-in method builtins.print}
     2387    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
```

This is already fast enough to pass the HackerRank time limit. But you can save another 0.6 seconds or so by making these changes:

1. Drop the calls to [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip): there's no need for them, because [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with no arguments has the same effect.
2. There's no need to construct the list `a` of edges: it's simpler just to construct the adjacency matrix directly from the input.
3. There's no need to deduplicate the edges (duplicate edges don't affect the correctness of Dikjstra's algorithm), but if you are going to do it, it's simpler to make `adj` into a list of sets, and call the `add` method instead of `append` so that the deduplication happens as you go along.